# CMake: link options

Tags: android, c++, cmake, linker

I have an Android CMakeList.txt that defines multiple target libararies (static and dynamic).
For one of these libraries I need to pass the -Wl,--version-script with a specific version script, to achieve this I'm using target_link_libraries:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib1
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}
        -Wl,--version-script=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../../native1.map
        )
```

Unfortunately the -Wl option is added to all the other libraries I'm targeting causing me any sort of linking issues because native1.map refers to the functions in native-lib1 only.
I've also tried to use target_link_options and add_link_options but Android Studio returns error saying these are not valid CMake commands.

Is there a way to define linker options for a single library targeted in CMakeList.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the option is treated as `PUBLIC` here. In general I recommend ***always*** specifying the "visibility" when using `target_***` commands.

In this case I'd recommend using `target_link_options` though, since this states the intention more clearly.

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib1
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}
        )
target_link_options(native-lib1
    PRIVATE 
        "-Wl,--version-script=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../../native1.map"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer fabian, unfortunately when trying to use target_link_options I get the following error:
`Unknown CMake command "target_link_options".`

Comment: I've probably found out the cause of the issue: even if I've installed CMake 3.18 it seems that my project is using 3.10, I'm now looking for a way to change CMake version

Comment: I confirm I needed to update my build.gradle to use cmake 3.18, now my project builds correctly.